# How to disable Google Analytics pageview in GTM?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I am building a SPA and I would like to have a full control over pageview tracking.
I have an Universal Analytics tag in GTM.

How can I disable initial pageview?

gtag.js has `send_page_view` option:

```
gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', { 'send_page_view': false });
```

How can I set something similar for Universal Analytics?

Comment: You can change the trigger to an event, I'm assuming that would solve your issue? https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679219?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

When tracking a SPA application it makes sent not using the default "Page View" trigger for Pageviews.

If you want to have full control over the Page View you should do two things

1. Implement a custom dataLayer push in your SPA.
2. Create a custom event trigger in GTM.

**Implement a custom dataLayer push in your SPA**
For example:

```js
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'custom_pageview',
  'additionalData1': 'optional data 1'
})
```

This push need to happen every time you want a page view tracked.

**Create a custom event trigger in GTM**

1. go to Trigger
2. add custom event trigger
3. as Event name chose the event you pushed in the dl: custom_pageview

[image: Screenshot of custom event trigger]

Now use this trigger for your google analytics page view tag.

Comment: I did that already but i need to disable regular pageview event as it doubles my custom pageview tracking

Comment: Note: I think I got an GTM trigger like this working like how @nikelone recommends... I may have unchecked 'Page changes based on browser history events' checkbox and even maybe turned off the 'Enhanced Measurement' entirely in my DataStream settings in GA4 just to be safe only my custom GTM event is triggering a pageview. 
Question: just curious, instead of 'custom_pageview', can you use 'page_view' or 'pageview' or are those considered 'special' event names? I thought I saw a person say you could just use page_view but thought I'd ask if anyone knows.